# Keras simplest conv network not learning anything

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I wrote simple code to learn Keras:

```
from tensorflow import keras


def main():
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

    model = keras.Sequential()

    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=4)

    model.summary()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But it seems to not learn anything. Not like it should learn much, but should at least decrease loss and increase accuracy a little. But both are stuck the same every epoch.

I had exact same model written in Pytorch and it achieved around 35% accuracy. This in tensorflow + keras is stuck on 10%.

tensorflow-gpu v1.9

What am I missing?

Comment: Your last layer should have a softmax activation.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr Oh, you are right. But didn't solve the problem. Network learns nothing with softmax output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the default learning rate is to high for this problem. Try something like

```
opt=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1.e-5)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Great, thank you! I actually tried higher learning rate because I figured out unnormalized input may be the problem. But it was other way around. Solved ;)

Comment: You are welcome! As also pointed out by user36624, normalizing the input is indeed a good idea when one uses many default settings.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the default learning rate used by `Adam` in both `keras` and `PyTorch`, and they both use `1e-3`. Therefore, learning rate should not be the issue, assume you use default in both models.

Alternatively, I think this is related to the weight initialization, which is explicitly handled by each layer in `keras` but not in `PyTorch`.

Simply changing the training line to the following,

> model.fit(x_train/255., y_train, shuffle=True,
>   validation_data=(x_test/255., y_test), epochs=4)

you should observe both training and validation accuracy reach around 60%.

I am not familiar with `PyTorch`, but I suggest you initialize the weights in the `keras` network with those used by the `PyTorch` network. In this way, you will have a fair comparison.

Comment: Good point. The default initialization will most likely work best with normalized input. Note however that the prefactors of the loss functions in keras and PyTorch may also differ (which would result in different step sizes as well).

Comment: Do you mean the `crossentropy` loss is implemented differently in `keras` and `PyTorch`?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. I haven't checked it, but it could be that they differ e.g. by a factor 1/(num. of classes). But maybe you are right and its just the initialization.